# How to read properties of DOM object via selenium Java API?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I need to read some properties of a DOM object via the selenium Java API. I'll explain my requirement via an example.

Let's say first I would like to find the `<g>` element highlighted in the Chrome Developer Tools (as shown below). I can easily do so via the Selenium Java API with the following code.

`WebElement gElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-id='node_grp_0_id52UVV33EHE7']"));`

Then I would like to read several properties of this `<g>` object via the Selenium Java API. So, I click on this `<g>` element in the Chrome Developer Tools and open the `Properties` view on the right hand side of the Chrome Developer Tools (as shown below) in order to find the path to various properties. After finding the paths, I now would like to read several of these properties (e.g. `ariaChecked` and `__data__.label`) via the Selenium Java API as shown below:

```
gElement.getAttribute("ariaChecked");
gElement.getAttribute("__data__.label");
```

Both the above mentioned lines of code returns null.

The following code also does not return the desired property values:

```
element.getCssValue("ariaChecked");
element.getCssValue("__data__.label");
```

Does anyone know how to read various properties of a DOM object (listed in the Properties view of the Chrome Developer Tools as shown below) via the selenium Java API?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to read a property of a web element via Java Script as shown below. Nested properties are also supported by this workaround:

```
public String getProperty(final String name) {
    return getJavascriptExecutor().executeScript("return arguments[0]." + name + ";", webElement).toString();
}
```

The above method can be invoked as shown below:

```
String name = getProperty("name");
```

or

```
String label = getProperty("__data__.label"); // This is a nested property.
```